# REVTex-like affiliation& author command

Tags: etoolbox

I am trying to implement my own version of `\affiliation` and `\author` to use in my  posters.
I would like to have options to show indices of affiliations in the form of `\arabic`, `\alph` and `\fnsymbol`. 
Arabic and alph outputs both work correctly, but not `\fnsymbol`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\alph{x},}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\alph{x}}
Authorname$^{\csuse{tmp}}$ %
\setcounter{x}{0}
\csxdef{tmp}{}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\arabic{x},}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\arabic{x}}
Authorname$^{\csuse{tmp}}$ %
\setcounter{x}{0}
\csxdef{tmp}{}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\fnsymbol{x},}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\fnsymbol{x}}
Authorname$^{\csuse{tmp}}$ %
\setcounter{x}{0}
\csxdef{tmp}{}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\alph{x},}
\stepcounter{x}
\csxdef{tmp}{\csuse{tmp}\alph{x}}
Authorname$^{\csuse{tmp}}$ %
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image: Output]

And error messages:

```
 Missing } inserted. ...csuse{tmp} $\to$ Authorname$^{\csuse{tmp}
```

I understand, that `\fnsymbol` produces math-mode output, and my code is missing proper switching between text and math modes, but I cannot find where this happens.

Comment: In general, I find simple solution: instead of putting indices into superscript in formula - just use \raisebox{...}{\scriptsize{...}}.
But I still wonder if there is a proper solution

Comment: I can't say exactly where the problem lies (that's why I am posting this as a comment and not as answer), but using `\textsuperscript{...}` instead of `$^{...}$` seems to be fine.

Comment: @campa Thanks! At first, this makes the code cleaner.
However, I was not happy that the letters are roman, not italic, but I checked how `\textsuperscript` is implemented and made proper correction for my purpose.

Comment: Why do you use `\csuse` etc. here? I can't say whether they cause the problem, but it looks strange on first glance

Comment: @ChristianHupfer here I showed simple version  which fully reproduces the behavior of all my code including error.
My main function is the following:
`\newcommand{\printauthor}[1]{
    \csuse{author#1}$^{\csuse{authfa#1}}$%
}`
, where `auth#N` stores name of the author, and `authfa#N` - symbols, corresponding to affiliations (numbers, letters or fnsymbols).

Comment: The problem is that `\textasteriskcentered`, `\textdagger`, `\textdaggerdbl`, `\textparagraph` and `\textbardbl` don't survive `\edef` (or `\xdef` in your case). If your robustify those with `etoolbox's `\robustify` your code will compile. (I don't know what the *real* problem is, i.e., *why* they don't survive `\edef`, though. It seems to have to do with the OMS encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all, my messy final code is ready. My first experience in writing packages & using etoolbox.

```
% avauthors.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{avauthors}[2015/09/20 Authors and Affiliations]
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{xstring}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\avindex}[1]{\arabic{#1}}
\newif\if@alph\@alphfalse
\DeclareOption{alph}{\@alphtrue%
    \renewcommand{\avindex}[1]{\alph{#1}}%
}
\DeclareOption{fn}{\renewcommand{\avindex}[1]{\fnsymbol{#1}}}
\DeclareOption{roman}{\renewcommand{\avindex}[1]{\roman{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\superscript[1]{%
  \@superscript{\selectfont#1}%
}
\def\@superscript#1{%
   \if@alph
      {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\textit{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}}%italic for letters
   \else
      {\m@th\ensuremath{^{\mbox{\fontsize\sf@size\z@#1}}}}%
   \fi
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\newcounter{avnumauthor}
\newcounter{avnumaffil}
\newcounter{avnumauthaffil}
\newcounter{avnumaffils}
\newcounter{avaffilindex}
\newcounter{avcounta}
\newcounter{avcntb}
\newcounter{avcntc}
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{
    \stepcounter{avnumauthor}
    \setcounter{avnumaffil}{0}
    \listadd{\authors}{#1}
    \csdef{author\theavnumauthor}{#1}
}
\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{
    \stepcounter{avnumaffils}
    \stepcounter{avnumaffil}
    \stepcounter{avaffilindex}
    \stepcounter{avnumauthaffil}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\theavaffilindex}{
        \setcounter{avcounta}{\i}
            \IfStrEq
                {\csuse{affil\theavcounta}}
                {#1}
                {\setcounter{avaffilindex}{\theavcounta}
                    \addtocounter{avnumaffils}{-1}
                }{}
    }
    \csxdef{affil\theavaffilindex}{#1}
    \csxdef{affindex\theavnumauthaffil}{\theavaffilindex}
    \csxdef{auth\theavnumauthor}{\theavnumaffil}
    \setcounter{avaffilindex}{\theavnumaffils}
}
\newcommand{\processall}{
    \setcounter{avcounta}{0}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\theavnumauthor}{
        \stepcounter{avcntb}
        \csxdef{tmpb}{}%
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\csuse{auth\theavcntb}}{%
            \stepcounter{avcounta}%
            \setcounter{avcntc}{\csuse{affindex\theavcounta}}
            \csxdef{tmpb}{\csuse{tmpb}\avindex{avcntc}}
            \ifnum \j < \csuse{auth\theavcntb}
                \csxdef{tmpb}{\csuse{tmpb},}
            \fi
        }%
        \csxdef{authfa\theavcntb}{\csuse{tmpb}}
    }
}
\newcommand{\printauthor}[1]{
    \csuse{author#1}\superscript{\csuse{authfa#1}}%
}
\newcommand{\printaffil}[1]{
    \setcounter{avcntb}{#1}%
    \superscript{\avindex{avcntb}}\csuse{affil#1}
}
\endinput
```

WE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[fn]{avauthors} % no option: arabic; options: roman, alph and fn
\begin{document}
\author{Author A}
\affiliation{Physics Dept.}
\author{Author B}
\affiliation{Physics Dept.}
\affiliation{Chemistry Dept.}
\author{Author C}
\affiliation{Chemistry Dept.}
\affiliation{Biology Dept.}
\author{Author D}
\affiliation{Physics Dept.}
\affiliation{Geology Dept.}
\processall{}

\printauthor{1} 
\printauthor{2} 
\printauthor{3} 
\printauthor{4}

\printaffil{1} 
\printaffil{2} 
\printaffil{3} 
\printaffil{4} 
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: Output]